# can a method have more than one type of inputs?

Tags: java

I have a method and I want to have two types of inputs for it. for example :

this is my method :

```
     private int myMethod(/*inputs*/) {
        //do stuff
     }
```

and if I call it like `myMethod(5);` it does some actions. but if I call it like `myMethod(5 , Alex)` it does something very similar to last time but with different return types.

is it possible to do such a thing? I'm trying to avoid code duplication.

Comment: Yes you can define two different methods for that. That is known as method overloading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called method overloading. Yes you can do that. 
But you will have to write two methods

```java
private int myMethod(int input) {
        //do stuff
}
```

and

```java
private int myMethod(int input, String anotherInput) {
        //do stuff differently
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for sending multiple parameter with more than one type of input:

```
 public static void print( Object... values){
       for(Object d : values){
          System.out.println(d);
       }
 }
```

and then:

```
print("test","test1",1,2,3);
```

or see this example for one type input:

```
public void doSomething(int... integers)
  {
    for (int i : integers) 
    {
      ...
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

U can pass null value and check if its value is null and then do accordingly. If you are new to java, then try concepts of method overloading.

```
myMethod(int i, String s){
 if(s != null ){
  //do stuff
 }else{
  //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method with a paramter of ***a String Type Arrary*** .
if you had like avoiding duplicating (*method overloading*) 
 :

```
 private int myMethod(String [] in)
     {

     }
```

then you can convert the first -not only the first- value of the *String Array* that you pass to the method's parameter to any **DataType**

using the method  :  ***valueOf()***

```
int i = Integer.valueOf(in[0]);
```